# How to use \autoref to refer to a subfigure

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, subfloats, autoref

Let's say I have a figure that actually has two subfigures (but composited into a single file), is there a way that I could get autoref to output "Figure 1A" and "Figure 1B"?

What I'm hoping is that there is some way to pass extra into to the call to `\autoref{}` that it would use as a suffix (e.g. `\autoref{fig:foo,A}` -> "Figure 1A").

One option I'm considering is: `\hyperref[fig:foo]{Figure 1A}` but ideally I'd like the numbering to be automatic (so that it's robust to me changing the ordering of things later).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

The birds will appear in figure number \autoref{fig:foo}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{bar}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit convoluted but I guess you don't need that very often.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

The birds will appear in figure number \hyperref[fig:foo]{\autoref*{fig:foo}A}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{bar}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `\autoref` command of the [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package is already progammed to know what to do when it's creating a cross-reference to an object that's associated with a counter named `subfigure`.

You also need to select a package that helps create subfigures. One such package is the [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package, which provides environments called `subfigure` and `subtable`.

If you need to create cross-references to more than one `subfigure` at a time, I suggest you look into using the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package and its `\cref` user-level macro. The `\cref` command can be configured to act just like `\autoref` does when it's given a single argument. However, unlike `\autoref`, `\cref` can easily take multiple arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\includegraphics' command

\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subfigure' environment
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}} % per the OP's stated preference

\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}      % for '\autoref' macro
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref} % for '\cref' macro

\begin{document}

The birds will appear in \autoref{fig:barA} and in \autoref{fig:barB}.

The birds will appear in \cref{fig:barA,fig:barB}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip} % default: 1\baselineskip
  \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{barA}
    \label{fig:barA}
  \end{subfigure}%
\hspace{\fill}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{barB}
    \label{fig:barB}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:foo}.
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the width/spacing for each caption is set by the subfigure environment.

`\autoref` gets the counter name from the hyperref anchor name, which is then run through `\autorefname` (page 26 hyperref).  As it turns out, the subcaption package uses the same anchor for both caption and subcaptions, so it prints `Figure` instead of `Subfigure`.  The number comes from `\@currentlabel`, same as `\ref` (see `\labelformat` page 13 subcaption).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}% use upper case letters

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

The birds will appear in figure number \autoref{fig:foo} and \autoref{fig:bar}.

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}% need width to align captions

  
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
  \caption{foo}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
  \caption{bar}
  \label{fig:bar}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{main title}% or \phantomcaption
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```